# Property 'xxxx' does not exist on type yyyy from class implements

Tags: typescript

I am totally new from typescript I have no idea how can I handle the following code like python dictionary type. I would like to create a object (human) with only three property and another object(Person) that have all property from human and one extra property build by some attribution. and create a array of object and iterate it. All i know is I can create a interface to handle type of object but from visual studio code, I have error like **Property 'fName' does not exist on type 'Person'**

```
interface Human {
    fName: string,
    lName: string,
    gen: boolean,
};
class Person implements Human {
    fullname: string;
    constructor(
        private f:string,
        private l:string,
        private g:boolean) {
            this.fullname = `${f} ${l}`;
    }

}
let u: object[] = [
    {fName: 'f1', lName: 'l1', gen: true},
    {fName: 'f2', lName: 'l2', gen: false},
    {fName: 'f3', lName: 'l3', gen: true},
];
let users: Person[] = u.map((d) => new Person(d.fName, d.lName, d.gen))

user.forEach((d: Person) => {
    console.log(d.fName);
})
```

Comment: If you paste the code in your IDE of choice, you get a nice and expressive error for the issue at-hand: `Class 'Person' incorrectly implements interface 'Human'.
  Type 'Person' is missing the following properties from type 'Human': fName, lName, gen`

Comment: Have a look at [classes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#public-private-and-protected-modifiers) in the docs.